# SVN propedit ignore doesn't ignore all folder in it

Tags: svn

I have a folder that I don't want to ignore.

When I use `svn status` 
I get the following answer :

```
? Node.js Back and BBD scripts/node_modules
```

However when I use the command
`svn propedit svn:ignore .` and add :

```
Node.js Back and BBD scripts/node_modules
```

The svn status gives me the same message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I include a project in my main project. And each project have their own svn ignore rules.

So to ignore `Node.js Back and BBD scripts/node_modules` I only have to go to `Node.js Back and BBD scripts` and add `node_modules` with the command `svn propedit svn:ignore .`

To resume : The `svn status` on my main project raise the warning : `This file is not under version control` for my inner project. But to solve it I have to go to this inner project to add the ignore rule.